# Is there a way to use the list output from a jinja2 `range` function directly in a template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, supercollider

I'm using jinja2 to template a supercollider startup file.

I have a variable `{{ sc_option_numOutputBusChannels }}` from which I need to generate a list.

Specifically, if `sc_option_numOutputBusChannels = 8`, then I need to create the following list:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

for use in the line:

```
~dirt.start(57120, [0, 2, 4, 6]);
```

The function `range(0, sc_option_numOutputBusChannels, 2 )` outputs that list **exactly** as I need it, but I've been unable to find a way to use the output of `range` directly as a string in my template - eg these **don't** work:

```
~dirt.start(57120, {% range(0, sc_option_numOutputBusChannels, 2 ) %} );

~dirt.start(57120, {{ range(0, sc_option_numOutputBusChannels, 2 ) }} );
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: While I was able to quickly PoC what I suspected was wrong with your code, in the future it would be helpful to include what behavior you _are_ experiencing, along with the description "these don't work"

Comment: Can do, thanks for the feedback (and the answer, of course!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it is because `range` by itself is a generator, and thus needs a consumer to indicate to ansible that you're done with the generator pipeline; the most common one I know of is [`| list`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list)

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: ~dirt.start(57120, {{ range(0, sc_option_numOutputBusChannels, 2 ) | list }} );
```

Comment: thankyou! the concept of generators and consumers is new to me - something to look into :)

Comment: It's a carry-over from ansible+jinja2's python underpinnings: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator and is _especially_ handy for things like `range` which could, in theory, generate billions and billions of items, but after filtration may only be 5 of them